# ARKit placing objct on a plane

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm learning from a tutorial online on ARKit to place an object on a plane.

```
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y + Float(boxGeometry.height/2), hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
```

he uses the code above to place it at the location where you tap on the screen

what does this mean:

```
hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x
```

why is it columns.3 and not columns.0 for example?

Comment: In other lines, Can you post the link of the tutorial ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ARHitTestResult.worldTransform` is of type `matrix_float4x4`. So it's a 4x4 matrix. `.columns` are numbered from `0`, so the vector `(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)` is the three things at the top of the final column of the 4x4 vector.

You can safely assume that the bottom row of the matrix is `(0, 0, 0, 1)` and that positional vectors are of the form `(x, y, z, 1)`. So then look at what the matrix does when applied to a vector:

```
a b c d         x         a*x + b*y + c*z + d
e f g h         y         e*x + f*y + g*z + h
i j k l    *    z    =    i*x + j*y + k*z + l
0 0 0 1         1         1
```

The `(d, h, l)` don't get multiplied and are just added on as if they were a separate vector. It's the same as:

```
a b c         x         d
e f g    *    y    +    h
i j k         z         l
```

So, the top-left 3x3 part of the matrix does something to `(x, y, z)` but doesn't move it. E.g. if `(x, y, z)` is `(0, 0, 0)` at the start then it'll definitely still be `(0, 0, 0)` at the end. So the 3x3 matrix might rotate, scale, or do a bunch of other things, but can't be a translation.

`(d, h, l)` though, clearly is just a translation because it's just something you add on at the end. And the translation is what you want — it's how you get to the plane from the current camera position. So you can just pull it straight out.

Comment: Tommy I know this old and maybe I'm missing the point (having stumbled on a similar tutorial). But without inspecting the vector how would one know that it's column 3 you need? Does it come down to a standard around how these vectors are constructed in OPENGL or other 3d engines?

Answer (score -2):

That has to do with how simdtransform is laid out.  One of them is rotate, one is scale, and one is translate.  Column 3 pertains to the translate matrix